# Recursive Boolean method foreach control in a TableLayoutPanel

Tags: c#, winforms, recursion, boolean, tablelayoutpanel

I know I'm missing something basic, but I'm still new to recursion and it's difficult to know what to look for. I've done fine with void recursive methods, but this Boolean is tripping me up.

I need to check each Control in my TableLayoutPanel, see if it's a TextBox, then see if it has text in it. (If it does return true, if all the TextBoxes are empty, return false.)

This is what I'm starting with, and I understand why it doesn't work, but I can't figure out what the solution would be.

```
private bool CheckNewRecord(Control Con)
        {
            foreach (Control C in Con.Controls)
            {
                if (C is TextBox && ((TextBox)C).Text != "")
                {
                    return true;        
                }
                else
                {
                    return CheckNewRecord(C);            
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
```

I think what is happening is it gets to the last control and sees it doesn't have children, and kicks back false because it skips the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are just checking the children but not the parent. You also return `false` even if there are more children to check. Return only `true` immediately.

Instead of this recursive approach can i suggest you a different one using a `Queue<T>`?

```
public static bool ContainsNonEmptyTextBox(Control con)
{
    var controlQueue = new Queue<Control>();
    controlQueue.Enqueue(con);
    while (controlQueue.Count > 0)
    {
        Control current = controlQueue.Dequeue();
        TextBox txt = current as TextBox;
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(txt?.Text))
            return true;
        foreach (Control c in current.Controls)
            controlQueue.Enqueue(c);
    }
    return false;
}
```

In my opionion this is easier to read and to understand, no recursion at all.

I have also used the `as`- and the null-conditional- operators

Comment: Now you're just checking all of the children twice, while the OP's code is checking them once.

Comment: @Servy: i don't like recursion anyway, so i've shown a different one now

Comment: That's it! Thank you so much, I think I understand now. The thing I was missing was that it needs to return true all the way up if it is true at any point. I just couldn't see how to do it. I feel like I tried things like this, but I was declaring the dummy bool in the wrong spot. Anyway, thank you.

Comment: @WillLatourelle: i'm glad you got it working. But note that i've changed my answer now to suggest a different approach. Maybe you want to test it also.

Comment: That also works, thank you. This one I understand the logic less because I've never used Queue<T> before. Where is it removing the control from the queue? Sorry if the question is dumb. I just don't see how controlQueue.Count is decremented in the loop

Comment: @WillLatourelle: the `Enqueue` adds them and the `Dequeue` removes them